# Android add AndroidX library to non-androix project

Tags: java, android, androidx

I have an Android Application and i want to add this library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:1.0.0'
```

When I add it I get this error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-209:19 to override.
```

When I add this line:

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

I get this error:

```
Error:
tools:replace specified at line:23 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified
```

Any idea what is the problem? How I can add this library? Maybe I can add a previous version of this library?

From what I read it's related to `AndroidX`, But I don't want to update my project to AndroidX because it's an old project and this will cause me a lot of problems.

## EDIT

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: tools:replace specified at line:23 for attribute
> android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified

You should add both

```
 tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
 android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
```

Make sure, You added below in your **`gradle.properties`** file

```
  android.useAndroidX=true
  android.enableJetifier=true
```

**FYI**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ump:user-messaging-platform:1.0.0'
```

> We recommend updating your project to use the final version of the support library:
> version 28.0.0. This is because **AndroidX artifacts with version 1.0.0**
> are binary equivalent to the Support Library 28.0.0 artifacts.

Comment: But i don't want to use AndroidX

Comment: @YosiFZ Okay sir, Read FYI

Comment: `This is because AndroidX artifacts with version 1.0.0 are binary equivalent to the Support Library 28.0.0 artifacts`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using "Support Library 28.0.0", i edit my post and added my app dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Just enable to Jetifier to have the other dependencies name-space translated:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't want to upgrade my project to use AndroidX